# Including template parts from index.html (that is, files outside the _layouts folder)

Tags: include, jekyll, templating

How can I include template parts (head.html, footer.html, ...) into the `index.html` file (or from any other files outside the `_layout` folder) without using the layout engine. In short, I'd like to replicate the basic use of PHP `include`.

Using the tag `{% include head.html %}` ([docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes)) I get on the front-end the tag printed as text.

Comment: You can just do it !

Comment: It doesn't work: Using the tag {% include head.html %} I get on the front-end the tag printed as text.

Comment: This is not the expected behavior. Did you have a github repository? I'll try to reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to include the YAML Frontmatter for each file** (outside the `_includes` and `_layouts` folder) you want processed by the Liquid templating engine.

This means that, **in order for** liquid tags like `{% include head.html %}` and `{{ post.content }}` to be processed, **one must add** 3 dashes to the top of the file, newline, and 3 more dashes.

Example in **index.html** where you have `{% include %}` or `{{ liquid_tags }}`

```
---
---
<html>
  {% include head.html %}
</html>
```

Will allow Jekyll to properly parse the liquid tags and insert `head.html` (which must be located in the `_includes` directory for the `include` to work)
Or else you will have to use the `include_relative` tag [See this link to the docs, which you've linked in your question](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes)

**An empty YAML frontmatter** is allowed for Jekyll, it simply indicates that you want the file to be processed by Liquid and Markdown processed.

**Without any frontmatter** (i.e there are no 3 dashes, newline, 3 dashes) in the file, the file is simply copied verbatim (just like any other static files, e.g JavaScript, CSS) to the final output at the `_site` folder. This holds true when you want to use Jekyll's built in SASS converter as well. Refer to the documentation [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss), and also note the warning about how Jekyll processes all Asset files as highlighted there.

**All that being said**, if you have a particular layout that you will repeatedly use it is better to use the layout engine to reduce duplicate code, but I understand that it is better to avoid additional files in files in `_layout` if they are used once only (like for a special `index.html` file)

Comment: Is there any possibility to use *include_relative* to include some files from outside current repository like `{% include_relative /somerepository/somedir/footer.html %}`?

Comment: @hyip sorry for the late reply. Did you give it a shot? I don't have a Jekyll install readily available right now. I would imagine not though, you could try relative paths too like `../parent_dir/`.